# Delphi iOs how to detect hang up

Tags: ios, delphi

I need to programmatically detect in a Delphi iOs application eithter the hang up the call (either by the caller or the receiver person). 
That would be an extra if I would know the phone number.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Sorry, neither of these things are available to an app.

Comment: @Paulw11 As far as I can see, detecting call hangup is possible by using CallKit, 
providing an implementation for CXProviderDelegate, handling the providerPerformEndCallAction method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxproviderdelegate/1648264-provider?language=objc

Comment: The CXProviderDelegate methods are called when the system performs actions associated with the CXProvider managed by your own app - I.e. when your app implements a VOIP service.